# Puppet removes Foreman VirtualHosts when installing OpenStack

Tags: apache, puppet, theforeman

My introduction to Puppet and Foreman has been very painful, but I know there's a big community around it, so I'm hoping that someone can set me straight here.

I set up Foreman and Puppet using the Foreman-Installer and it went great. I had Foreman up and running and it worked great! However, I added the OpenStack controller role to the machine, it wiped out the Apache vhosts for Foreman. I've scoured Google and Github for copies of the vhost files, but with no luck.

So the main questions here:
1) How do I locate/generate the Foreman vhosts for Apache?
2) How do I prevent Puppet from removing them again?

Thanks in advance all you Puppet Masters!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To prevent Puppet from blasting your Apache config, start managing that config through Puppet.

I'm not sure how your OpenStack controller role works, but it likely employs the `puppetlabs-apache` module, which will purge unmanaged configuration. You should use this module to configure the Foreman vhost on the machine.

As for getting it back - Puppet should have stored the contents of deleted files in the `clientbucket`. Check the logs on that machine. There should be `md5` sums for all removed files. Use those to retrieve the contents, either through the `filebucket` tool, or by manually trudging `/var/lib/puppet/clientbucket` (or whatever `puppet agent --configprint clientbucketdir` yields).

Comment: Puppet seems overly convoluted to me, so I've moved on. But I did find the purged vhosts in `/var/lib/puppet/clientbucket` so thanks a ton!

Comment: It appears that Puppet blasted more than just my vhost configs anyway. Even Puppet itself doesn't work anymore. Back to square one it seems.

Comment: Ah well, if your Puppet master used Apache/Passenger, then yes, chances are that the master is no longer functional. Recovering from that through `filebucket` might be arduous, but should be possible.

Comment: I appreciate your insight into the matter. I ended up rebuilding without foreman, which I should have done to begin with. I definitely think I could have recovered using the method you suggested, but now I've got the opportunity to learn how Puppet works without all the fluff of a GUI.